# VSCode ipython cells are not clearing their output on running

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I've only encountered this in VSCode:
[why](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NK3qH.png)

I want to see only one, last output of the cell.

There are no such problem if cell contains print():
[with print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxIAz.png)

Version: 1.84.2 (system setup)
Commit: 1a5daa3a0231a0fbba4f14db7ec463cf99d7768e
Date: 2023-11-09T10:51:52.184Z
Electron: 25.9.2
ElectronBuildId: 24603566
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22631
Jupyter v2023.10.1100000000
Python v2023.21.13341009

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: if anyone is facing this, please add repro details and steps in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/203587.

Comment: does this still happen for you? are you using the data tables extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the "change presentation to" option choose VS Code builtin notebook output renderer(vscode.builtin-notebook-renderer). You may be facing the issue because the Jupyter extension version is marking it to something else.

Happy coding!!

[image]

Comment: you said you had this issue. what was it set to for you before you changed it to the builtin notebook renderer?

Answer (score 0):

Updates extension to the latest version or use a pre-release version.

[image]

In addition, this may be related to your operation method. You can use the following method to clear the output in the output panel.

[image]

Comment: Switching to pre-release version doesn't work and alt+del cleaning is pretty inconvenient to use each time before re-running same cell

Comment: Delete all settings or completely reinstall vscode and try again.